# Economic Sentence Translation help

Tags: grammar, translation

> 首相は
>   「想定の利益が出ないなら当然支払いに影響する。
>   **給付に耐える状況にない場合は、給付で調整するしかない**」
>    と述べ、

This is more a need for translation help.
I am going to share my analysis about this text.

> The prime minister said
>   [If the supposed profit will not arrive, of course it will have influence on payments.
>   If it looks like we come to a situation where we cannot bear the payments, we will make adjustment through them (The payments).]

にない=Negative of 似る
給付で調整するしかない= I think で in this case has the meaning of "by means of".

Here is the source:
http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/hl?a=20160215-00000074-jij-pol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking just at the bolded part, here's a different take on it:

- *"If circumstances do not support [the current level of] benefits, then our only recourse is to adjust benefit [levels]."*

The bits in square brackets are implied in the Japanese, and help make the English more idiomatic.  More about this below in **Breaking it Down**.

### Key Points

- 給付{きゅうふ} more commonly refers to *"benefits"*, as in bonuses, paid vacation, housing allowances, that kind of thing -- in the context of this article, specifically 年金給付: retirement pension benefits.
- にない here is に + ない *"not in (a place, circumstance, etc.)"*, not 似ない *"doesn't resemble"*.
- Your interpretation of で in the second clause seems to fit.

### Breaking It Down

- 給付に耐える状況にない場合は →

  - 給付 *"benefits"*
  - に *"at, to, against"*, etc.
  - 耐える *"stand up to, resist"*, also *"to merit, to be worth"*, by extension from *"to be able to stand up to*"

  The above all modifies 状況 *"circumstances, conditions, situation"*, producing *"circumstances that can withstand benefits"*

  Idiomatically, one generally doesn't talk about *"benefits"* this way in English: what is ultimately being talked about is the **cost** of providing these benefits, which can also be described as the **level** of benefits.

  Furthermore, circumstances in English don't *withstand* or *endure* a level of spending, they **support** a level of spending.

  - XX 状況にある場合 / XX 状況にない場合
    場合 is a bit of an idiomatic Japanese term.  The above phrases basically mean *"if / when in XX circumstances"* and *"if / when **not** in XX circumstances"*.
- 給付で調整するしかない →

  - 給付 *"benefits"*
  - で indicating instrumental, *"by means of"*
  - 調整する *"to adjust"*
  - XX しかない *"nothing but XX"* → *"we can do nothing but XX, we have no recourse but XX"*

  The implied object of the adjustment is spending.  "To adjust spending by means of benefits" effectively means "adjusting benefit spending itself", so as English, it is clearer to simply say this directly: *"to adjust benefit levels"*.

Answer (score 1):

You made one mistake, but ***only accidentally***, it did not affect your translation too badly.  The mistake is in thinking that:

> "にない = Negative of [似]{に}る (= to not look like)"

「にない」, in this context, is particle 「に」 + 「ない」.  It has nothing to do with the verb 「似る」.

> 「A[状況]{じょうきょう}に**ある**」 = "(something) is in situation A".
>
> 「A状況に**ない**」 = "(something) is **not** in situation A"

(I also need to point out that it is ***not*** possible or grammatical to say 「状況似ない」 to begin with.  You need a particle in between, which happens to be a 「に」.)

The rest of your understanding is indeed excellent.

The part 「[給付]{きゅうふ}に[耐]{た}える状況にない[場合]{ばあい}」 could be translated as:

> "In case we do not find ourselves in a situation to bear the payments"

This TL is pretty literal, of course.

Answer (score 0):

“…にない” means “not in the situation / status.” Even though you misunderstood this part as “the negative of 似る,” your translation of the quoted sentence isn’t too much off the mark.

You can simply change the first few words:

> In case we should come to a situation where we cannot bear the payments, we will make adjustment through them (The payments).